# Crash with iAd only on iOS 7 - weak delegate is bad pointer

Tags: ios, iad, weak-references

I'm getting a strange crash with the iAd error callback. Here is my crash log:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x2281
0com.apple.main-thread Crashed
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_retain + 17
1    YouDoodle AdView.m line 265 -[AdContainerView requestGAD]
2    iAd     -[ADBannerView _forwardErrorToDelegate:] + 254
3    iAd     -[ADBannerView serverBannerViewDidFailToReceiveAdWithError:] + 178
4    iAd     -[ADAdSpace setServiceAdSpace:] + 472
5    CoreFoundation  __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
6    CoreFoundation  _CFXNotificationPost + 1718
7    Foundation  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 76
8    Foundation  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30
9    iAd     -[ADAdSheetProxy _adSheetConnectionLost] + 292
10 ...   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
11   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 22
12   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 274
13   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
14   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
15   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
16   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
17   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 138
18   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1136
19   YouDoodle  
AppDelegate.m line 129
main
```

http://crashes.to/s/c654d14dcfa

delegate callback for iAd:

```
- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    DLog(@"IAD Failed to load with error %@", error);

    self.adBannerContainer.hidden = YES;

    if (InternetAvailableWithAlert(NO))
    {
        if (self.gadAvailable)
        {
            self.gadBannerContainer.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            [self requestGAD];
        }
    }
}

- (void) requestGAD
{
    GADRequest* request = [[GADRequest alloc] init];

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

    request.testDevices = @[GAD_SIMULATOR_ID];

#endif

    self.gadBanner.rootViewController = (self.gadBanner.rootViewController ?: self.viewController);
    [self.gadBanner loadRequest:request];
}
```

The iAd view delegate is a singleton which is never released. Even if it was released, the iAd class delegate property is a weak property so it should auto-nil.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ADBannerViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Ideas?

Comment: It looks like the crash is happening inside your `[AdContainerView requestGAD]` method.  What does that method look like?  What's on line 265?

Comment: @BrianNickel I updated the question with the delegate callback for iAd. Line 265 is near the bottom.

Comment: @BrianNickel In this case, self IS the delegate so it should either be a valid pointer to a valid object or nil in which case the delegate callback shouldn't happen unless I'm missing something. Doesn't happen on iOS 6 so it makes me think it's an iOS 7 bug.

Comment: What I'm getting from the crash report is that the crash occurs inside `requestGAD` not on the call to `requestGAD`.

Comment: So you think Crashlytics just missed the line inside requestGAD that caused the crash?

Comment: Did some more logging in my Crashlytics and the crash definitely happens when it tries to call the requestGAD method. None of my CLS_LOG log statements from inside that method appear.

Comment: Could be happening before your logs (or in your log function call).  The crash is happening on `objc_retain` which could be any strong variable assignment.  Can you post some of `requestGAD`?

Comment: @BrianNickel added the code from requestGAD

Comment: Nothing is really jumping out as a point where ARC would inject a retain.  You could try looking in assembly view too see where `L_objc_retain$stub`.  I would guess that `self.viewController`, `self.gadBanner` or `self.gadBanner.rootViewController` is a zombie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to setting the Admob SDK root view controller back to itself, when the view controller has been deallocated, this crashes. Admob SDK uses an assign reference instead of weak which is why it crashed.