# Crash with iAd trying to present view controller

Tags: ios, iad

I'm getting a crash with iAd saying that it can't present a modal view controller while a transition is in progress. What is the fix for this? I have no control over how iAd presents the view controller in response to a tap...

Crash log:

http://crashes.to/s/8454c6d34cf

```
Fatal Exception NSInternalInconsistencyException
Attempting to begin a modal transition from <UINavigationController: 0x15e2cd80> to <_ADRemoteViewController: 0x171d58d0> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed
0 ...    CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_exception_throw + 38
2    CoreFoundation  +[NSException raise:format:]
3    Foundation  -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
4    UIKit   -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 244
5    UIKit   -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4668
6    iAd     -[ADAdSpace _considerPresentingActionViewController] + 1642
7 ...    libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
8    libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 22
9    libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 268
10   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
11   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
12   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
13   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
14   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 138
15   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1136
16   YouDoodle  
AppDelegate.m line 158
main
17   YouDoodle   start + 16888
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crash with iAd only on iOS 7 - weak delegate is bad pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010684/crash-with-iad-only-on-ios-7-weak-delegate-is-bad-pointer) -- Why post twice?

Comment: @Cyrille This is a completely different question. Look at the question more closely.

Comment: Yeah, this is an iAd crash. The linked question is Admob. @PsychoDad, did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing it from our Raygun emails. Is it just a random bug in iAd?

Comment: From what I can tell it's a bug in iAd. I've logged a bug with Apple and they say it's fixed in iOS 8.